# ASP.net MVC 5 ViewBag using Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

Hey all I'm new to MVC/Razor and I am wanting to simply display a year on the view page.

The view page code:

```
<p>&copy; @Html.Raw(ViewBag.theDate) - Switchboard</p>
```

And my controller code:

```
public String getYear()
{
    ViewBag.theDate = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

    return View(ViewBag.theDate);
}
```

When viewing the page in IE it just prints out:

> © - Switchboard

How can I call that controller function from my View using Razor?

Comment: All the answers are solid options... (not that I want to add to the confusion if you are still learning) But if this is something small and that warrants re-use you could consider using a `helper`. (E.g if you have multiple views that all need this value, and you're not using it on the master page. Key being "re-use") https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs... again just see what your use case is, and assess it from there onward. example: `<%= Helper.Copyright("Switchboard") %>`

Comment: Why not just `@DateTime.Now.Year.ToString() - Switchboard` in the view - you don't need `ViewBag` for this

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need a controller method, to use the ViewBag and to return a View

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.theDate = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
    return View();
}
```

In the `Index.cshtml`, simply use

```
<p>&copy; @ViewBag.theDate - Switchboard</p>
```

Comment: How do I call something from a method other than Index()?

Comment: the MVC pattern requires you tu use a controller method to return a view. In that method you can call other method from other services.
Ex `ViewBag.theDate = DateHelper.getYear()`

Answer (score 2):

You can use ViewData as well, like

```
ViewData["Year"] = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(); // in controller/actionresult
```

and in your view(Razor) just write:

```
@ViewData["Year"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a controller `ActionResult` that returns a View, like so:

```
public ActionResult MyView()
{
    //ViewBag.ShowTheYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

    //You do not call a method from the view.. you do it in the controller..

    // Using your example

    ViewBag.ShowTheYear = getYear();

    return View();
}
```

`getYear` method:

```
public String getYear()
{
    return DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
}
```

Then in your MyView.cshtml

```
<p>&copy; @Html.Raw(ViewBag.ShowTheYear) - Switchboard</p>
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: That does help. Thanks BviLLe_Kid